# Erlang - is it OK to  send(..) simultaneously on tcp socket from different processes?

Tags: erlang

I need to send stuff on a tcp socket from different processes.
Is it allowed to send simultaneously on same socket? If not, how sychonization can be achieved?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes, a socket behaves like a process, accepting messages from any other process. Just be aware, if the order of messages is important, that the order of messages sent cannot be guaranteed (only the order of messages per sending process).

Comment: Note that each send is an atomic operation even though they may come from different processes. This means that there will be no intermixing of the data in the sends. But do note what @AdamLindberg said about message ordering!